# What is the difference between "bluverda", "verdblua" and "blua kaj verda"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-formation, colors

Is there a special meaning when several colors are compounded?

Comment: I looked for "bluverd" and "verdblu" at [Tekstaro.com](http://tekstaro.com/). Both are found in its database (meaning both are likely correct), and together they have 3 hits. But what most interests me is that two of those hits come from the same book (Kastelo de Prelongo), where the two variations seem to be used interchangably. One time the eyes of Fraŭlino de Prelongo are described as "grandaj **bluverd**aj okuloj," and another time as "grandaj okuloj, de ekstermara **verdblu**eco."

Answer (score 6):

*Blua kaj verda* means an object is part blue and part green. *Bluverda* is a color that is between green and blue, such as the one in the following image which is a red 0, green 122, and blue 116.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

The principle word comes last; so you'd call a colour between green and blue *verdblua* if you'd call it blue if you were forced to pick either green or blue and *bluverda* if you'd go for green.

With *kaj* you have a mixture, some parts green, some blue.

Comment: Estu *ver**d**a*, ne *ver**t**a*.